# Почему Axios не отправляет Cookie на бек сайт?

Tags: php, rest, cookie, axios

Мой React js SPA на http://localhost:3000 бек на http://api.f-mania (rest api php).
В React js использую axios credentials вставил true:

```
axios.interceptors.request.use((config) => {
  config.withCredentials = true;
  return config;
});
```

в бек вставил:

```
// Headers
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:3000');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *');
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

Выполняю GET запрос в бек но Куки не отправляется хотя в SPA есть cookie.

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно включить переменную [crossDomain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342140/cross-domain-cookies) для вашего AJAX запроса, НО это будет работать только между суб-доменами с одним и тем же TLD. Также рекомендую прочитать про недавнее введение [безопасности](https://blog.sibirix.ru/2020/03/02/cookie-end/) для печенек.